# How to Pass File without full Path?

Tags: java, file, servletcontextlistener

I created Simple program for File update throgh java Program

```
public class AppendToFileExample {

private static final String FILENAME = "TestFile.txt";

public static void main(String[] args) {

    BufferedWriter bw = null;
    FileWriter fw = null;

    try {

        String data = " This is new content after edit";

        File file = new File(FILENAME);
        fw = new FileWriter(file, true);
        bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        bw.write(data);
        System.out.println("Done");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (bw != null)
                bw.close();
            if (fw != null)
                fw.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        }
    }
  }
```

Which is working successfully
But Then i tried to do same thing with the help of ServletContextListener but with servlet everything working fine except I have to put Full file path like this

```
 String FILENAME = "C:\\Users\\admin\\workspacetasks\\UpdateText\\TestFile.txt";
```

With this full path its working fine but its not updating file when i try to pass only file name like this

```
 String FILENAME = "test.txt";
```

So my question is how to pass file without full path of file..Is there any other way or anything?or any link for reference?
Thank You.

Below is mine ServletContextListener

```
public class StartupListener implements ServletContextListener {

private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(StartupListener.class);
@Override
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
    System.out.println("contextInitialized");
    UpdateTextFile updateTextFile = new UpdateTextFile();   
    System.out.println("Before");
    updateTextFile.exec();
    System.out.println("after");
}
@Override
public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

and then this will call method in java program that program is here

```
 public class UpdateTextFile 
{
    private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(UpdateTextFile.class);
     public void exec() {
  //        String FILENAME = "C:\\Users\\admin\\workspacetasks\\UpdateText\\TestFile.txt";
      String FILENAME = "TestFile.txt";
      System.out.println("Inside exce ");
      BufferedWriter bw = null;
      FileWriter fw = null;
     try {
        String data = "Aloha after edit \n";
        System.out.println(data);
        File file = new File(FILENAME);
        System.out.println(FILENAME);
        System.out.println("Before FileWriter");
        fw = new FileWriter(file, true);
        System.out.println("After FileWriter");
        System.out.println("Before BufferedWriter");
        bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        System.out.println("After BufferedWriter");
        System.out.println("Before Write Data");
        bw.write(data);
        System.out.println("After Write Data");
        System.out.println("Done");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (bw != null)
                bw.close();
            if (fw != null)
                fw.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
     }
  } 
 }
```

Comment: That is because your `Servlet` might be having a different class-path than your Java application. If you get a `FileNotFoundException`, it will tell where the Servlet is actually trying to look for the file. Just put the file there

Comment: @soufrk surprisingly its not even throwing FileNotFoundException or any Exception....its printing logs in Tomcat as well as printing System.out.println in console...its just not editing test.txt file

Comment: @soufrk It has exactly nothing to do with the classpath. It has to do with the current working directory of the servlet container.

Comment: @EJP so is there anything wrong in my code? or there is another way?What you suggesting?

Comment: @vik666 If your code doesn't throw any exceptions, the file is being created, just not where you think. NB The `exists()` test and `createNewFile()` calls are both complete wastes of time. `new FileOutputStream()` already does that, so you're forcing the system to do it all twice, as well as deleting the file you just created. You don't need to call `getAbsoluteFile()` either: the `File` alone is sufficient. You do however need to close the `BufferedWriter`.

Comment: Can you update with complete the `try` block code, relevantly the file handling part

Comment: @EJP I just updated my question with Java file where I am calling through ServletContextListener..And yes I did whatever You said above..it worked with normal Java program but yet no progress while doing same through ServletContextListener

Comment: @soufrk ok let me edit with all files...so it will be clear to understand

Comment: @soufrk The only 'file handling part' we need to see is what is already posted. The only other 'file handling part' should be more writes and a close, none of which affect the creation of the file. Unless OP is deleting it.

Answer (score 0):

If your code doesn't throw any exceptions, the file is definitely being created, just not where you think. A file with a relative path will be created relative to the current working directory of your application, whatever that may be. In the case of a servlet container it certainly won't be anywhere inside the webapp's own directory. For example in Tomcat it might be Tomcat's `bin` directory.

NB:

1. Contrary to the now-deleted answer by @SilvanBregy, the CWD of an application doesn't necessarily have anything to do with where its own JAR file is located, and contrary to the comment by @soufrk it has exactly nothing to do with the classpath.
2. The `exists()` test and `createNewFile()` calls are both complete wastes of time. `new FileOutputStream()` already does that, so you're forcing the system to do it all twice, as well as deleting the file you just created.
3. You don't need to call `getAbsoluteFile()` either: the `File` alone is sufficient.
4. You do however need to close the `BufferedWriter`.

Comment: yes i did what you said in point 2 and 3..if you see my Java code Filename=fullpath/test.txt  is working when i pass full path..its just not working when i pass Filename = "test.txt"...no exception in console

Comment: @vik666 What do you mean by `its just not working` ? It's just that, the code will generate the file in either an absolute path, or a path relative to the `Servlet`. Print `getAbsoluteFile()` after the write operation, and check the same location.

Comment: @vik666 It ***is*** working, if there is no exception and no delete. You are looking in the wrong place for the file. Simple as that.

Comment: @soufrk Wrong again. Third time. It is not 'relative to the Servlet'. It has exactly nothing to do with the Servlet whatsoever. Possibly you could stop posting guesswork and misinformation here.

Comment: @EJP yes file is there in workspace but its not updating content which i am trying to send throgh code

Comment: @vik666 I didn't say anything about a workspace. The code you posted (a) creates and (b) writes to a file named `TestFile.txt` in the current working directory of your servlet container. The file in the workspace is left over from when you specified the full path. Surely this is obvious?

Comment: @EJP Now you see the problem. A file at some location is being anticipated to be changed by the Servlet. The guesswork is to understand the view with which someone asks a question, not being technically correct, no offence.

Comment: @EJP yes its done..it was silly mistake..I was looking for file in Workspace but with the help of System.getProperty("user.dir") i got file not found exception and with that i got exact path where file were created..those text files are created in Eclipse foldwe where eclipse is installed

Comment: Exactly as I stated two hours ago.

Comment: @soufrk The problem was evident right ftom the start, as my comments and answer show, and the solution is by definition 'technically correct', as opposed to a whole lot of erroneous waffling about classpaths and 'relevantly the file handling part' and 'relative to the Servlet', which only added to the confusion. Please stop it. Now.

Comment: @EJP Yes have to change working directory from config which was set to folder where eclipse installed...have to change that directory to my workspace

Comment: @vik666 The solution is not to frick around with Tomcat starting conditions but to look for the file in the right place in the first place, or, if you need to determine the right place, to *specify* it in the first place. Possibly you are looking for `ServletContext.getRealPath()`?

Answer (score -1):

**Yes its SOLVED**.If any one in future have same problem then
just click right on program Run As > Run Configuration > Tomcat 8 on left panel > Arguments and then set Other working directory as you want...
Dont know its correct approach to do but thats what i got..if any one get any other way without changing working directory then please share else if i get any i will post it

Comment: What if another servlet want to write another relative file somewhere else?

Comment: well there you can use System.getProperty("user.home") which takes you  to here C:\Users\admin then in code its just you need to add your workspace and project name....in this case you dont need to update any arguments in tomcat